# Store user state by userid or emailid in server, which user Uninstalled Android App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM in my app. Currently, when a user logs-out, I remove the corresponding registration token in my App Server to make the user *not active*. I was wondering if I should do the same thing if the user uninstalls the app?

Also, is there a way to check if the FCM registration token is valid or not?

Comment: Hi. I've edited out your post, trying to understand it as much as I can, and aligned it with the usual terms when using FCM (e.g FCM user id to Registration token). Please feel free to undo my changes if you think it's way different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40706603/how-can-i-know-that-a-firebase-cloud-messaging-token-is-out-of-use/40734449#40734449

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, when the app is uninstalled, the registration token is *invalidated* and will be discarded by FCM, and in turn it is the developer's responsibility to remove the corresponding token from their App Servers.

For the checking the validity of a registration token on the server-side, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41560628/4625829).

Comment: Cool , So there is no way when uninstalling app. Only form server side we can detect about it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *checking it when uninstalling the app*.